# How to disable the 'add' item button, once user already added the item to list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items in an array. I looped through that array and it dynamically shows the items list with `add` and `remove` buttons.

`add` and `remove` buttons performs add or remove actions on the items to the users newly list.

Now I'm trying that if the user added the item once in cart or list then the button gets disabled. So, it won't add the same item again and again in his list or cart.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
<div>
    {list.map((shoe) => (
        <div key={shoe.id}>
            <h5>{shoe.name}</h5>
            <button onClick={() => addItem(shoe)}>add</button>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(shoe.id)}>remove</button>
        </div>
    )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you add the shoe to the cart, but if you add the IDs only you could do something like:

`<button disabled={cart.includes(shoe.id)}>...</button>`

Comment: by clicking on the button I'm sending the whole item to my reducer function which add the item in cart.

Comment: okay then you can do it like: `<button disabled={cart.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === shoe.id)}>...</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Store a map of `id`'s that have been added, lookup and set `disabled` attribute of button if `shoe.id` exists in the map. Update the add and remove item handlers to also update the added id state.

```
const [added, setAdded] = useState({});

...

const addItem(shoe) => {
  ...
  setAdded(added => ({ ...added, [shoe.id]: shoe.id }));
  ...
};

...

const removeItem(id) => {
  ...
  setAdded(added => {
    const nextAdded = { ...added };
    delete nextAdded[id];
    return nextAdded;
  });
  ...
};

...

<div>
  {list.map((shoe) => (
    <div key={shoe.id}>
      <h5>{shoe.name}</h5>
      <button
        disabled={added[shoe.id]}
        onClick={() => addItem(shoe)}
      >
        add
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => removeItem(shoe.id)}>remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

checking if shoe is already present in your cart and then setting the disabled property true accordingly is I suppose the best way.

another approach you can use is to have a disabled property within your shoe object and in your addItem function make that true whenever you add shoe to cart.if space is not an issue this would be also great.

```
<button disabled={shoe.disabled} onClick={() => addItem(shoe)}>add</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a class to hide it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const onButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.target.classList.add('hidden');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={e => onButtonClick(e)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

css :

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is [the repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-r1xg85?file=index.js)